# preg_match() with scape character is not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I Want to Detect This string :

```
C:\wamp\www
```

and this is my function:

```
function remove_path($line) {
if (preg_match("/^C:\wamp\www$/", $line)) {
$new_line = str_replace("C:\wamp\www","",$line);
echo "FOUND";
//return $new_line;
} else {
//return $line;
echo " NOT FOUND";
}
}

$line = "C:\wamp\www\project";
remove_path($line);
```

but it seems the pattern is not working,
what is the problem ?

Comment: Your pattern contains `\w` which means something else to regular expressions. You should escape your backslashes by double backslashing

Comment: More importantly the `$` hinders comparing the remainder of the input path. And if you're already using that approach, `preg_replace()` would avoid the `if` and subsequent replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is not escaped and then you should be aware of probable used tokens inside. There is a token `\Q..\E` for that purpose. Use this as your regex:

```
/^\QC:\wamp\www\E$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your backslashes to have them be literal backslashes. Otherwise PHP thinks they are escape characters:

```
if (preg_match("/^C:\\wamp\\www$/", $line)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) if you are searching for a constant pattern:

```
if(strpos($string, 'C:\wamp\www\') === 0) {
    // do it
}
```

Also note that I've added a \ at the end. If you miss that, the pattern would also match paths like `C:\wamp\www2`

Comment: This is the proper way to do this

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @IanBrindley not really. Using a regex engine to search for a constant pattern introduces unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @hek2mgl It was a joke. Obviously not a very funny one.

Comment: Actually the anchored regex might be speedier here, as `strpos` probes through the whole string, and the PHP expression checks only afterwards if it actually matched at the start. [`strncmp`](http://php.net/strncmp) would be more canonical. Also, there's an unescaped backslash at the end of the string.

Comment: @mario Can't really believe this as strpos returns the position of the *first* match only. If it would really iterate over the whole string it would be a bug. Will need to read the source code.

Comment: @mario You are wrong, check the source: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.h#L273  (Really couldn't believe it)

Comment: Yes, obviously. It still iterates over the whole input string for non-matches.

Comment: @mario Ah, now I got your concern. Having this, you are right, there will be a threshold in the length of `$string` where preg_match from the start of the string will be faster. Good point!

Answer (score 0):

\w has a special meaning in regex, it is equivelant to class characters [a-zA-Z0-9]
So you need to escape it as `\\w`, however PHP interprets `\\` as `\` and again you end up with `\w`, so you really need to escape them as `\\\w`:

```
 preg_match("/^C:\\\wamp\\\www$/", $line))
```